# How to use an expression or formula on values from IMPORTRANGE

Tags: google-sheets, importrange

I am trying to use an expression on the values that are imported from another spreadsheet. The IMPORTRANGE copies the raw data, and with QUERY I can then specify which columns to use, so I can skip some of them.

However, I want to process the imported values by some expression. The QUERY doesn't seem to support different string functions like LEN, etc. But if I use an expression over the QUERY, like "=LEN(QUERY(...", then I get only one record as a result, not a list of rows, as I would from IMPORTRANGE and QUERY.

Specifically, I have a source spreadsheet, that is filled automatically by one of my Google Forms, and there is a column with a list of personal names. This source spreadsheet is restricted to only a few users. But I have create another spreadsheet, for the public use. In this copy, I want to display all the non-sensitive columns, but for the personal names column, I want to display only a number of the names, which are comma-separated. The expression to get the number of the names is otherwise trivial:

`=IF(LEN(TRIM(A1)) > 0; COUNTA(SPLIT(A1; ",")); "")`

I could use the expression in the source spreadsheet, but it's overwritten by Google Forms. So I need to use the expression in the copied spreadsheet.

What are the possible solutions? I haven't found any questions similar to mine.

Comment: Welcome to [webapp.se]. Please add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: @Rubén I used Google search with different terms like "google sheets expression with importrange" and similar. Also a search in the google support forum and a search in stackoverflow. Found many great things, but none about combining expressions/formula with importrange.

Comment: The term `expression` is rarely used on posts related to Google Sheets. As you already got an answer I suggest to explore the tags [tag:google-sheets] and [tag:importrange] (among the other tags o this site)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that you build the "count" in a second sheet of the Google Forms Response Spreadsheet, and then reference it using `importrange`.

Suppose that your Google Forms Response Sheet looks like this:

---

[image: Google Forms]

---

- Create a new sheet in the same spreadsheet, say the sheet name = "Count".
- Put a header in Cell A1,
- Insert this formula in cell A2:

`=ArrayFormula(if(len('Form Responses 1'!C2:C),len('Form Responses 1'!C2:C)-len(REGEXREPLACE('Form Responses 1'!C2:C,",",""))+1,))`

The output should look like this:

---

[image: Count output]

---

In the external spreadsheet, insert these formula in the following cells:

- Cell A1: `=importrange("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/<<insert spreadsheet id>>","Form Responses 1!A1:B")`
- Cell C1: `=importrange("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/<<insert spreadsheet id>>","Count!A1:A")`
- Cell D1: `=importrange("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/<<insert spreadsheet id>>","Form Responses 1!D1:E")`

The output should look like this:

---

[image: Linked count]

---

Props: infospired.com [How to Count Comma Separated Words in a Cell in Google Sheets](https://infoinspired.com/google-docs/spreadsheet/count-comma-separated-words-google-sheets/)

Comment: Wow, thanks, great answer, and fast, less than a day from the question. I haven't thought of having a second sheet in the primary spreadsheet. I am grateful, thanks.

Comment: @ButlNor Please read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)